# Why is my global, extern lambda variable not initialized at runtime?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, global-variables

I am implementing [parser combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_combinator) by composing C++ lambdas.

For example:

```
// rule_character.cpp
#include "rule_character.hpp"

LexerRule character_name =
    (make_terminal("alarm") & replace_with("\a")
        | (make_terminal("backspace") & replace_with("\b"))
        | (make_terminal("delete") & replace_with("\x7f"))
        | (make_terminal("escape") & replace_with("\x1b"))
        | (make_terminal("newline") & replace_with("\n"))
        | (make_terminal("null") & replace_with("\0"))
        | (make_terminal("return") & replace_with("\r"))
        | (make_terminal("space") & replace_with(" "))
        | (make_terminal("tab") & replace_with("\t"))) / "character-name";

LexerRule character =
    ((make_terminal("#\\") & ignore_string) +
        (character_name
            | ((make_terminal("x") & ignore_string)
                + (hex_scalar_value & replace_hex_scalar_value))
            | (make_class([](char c) { return true; }, "any-character"))))
        / "character";
```

where `LexerRule` is an alias for a `std::function` type.

Here is the header:

```
// rule_character.hpp
extern LexerRule character_name;
extern LexerRule character;
```

In `main.cpp`, however, a `std::bad_function_call` is being thrown:

```
// main.cpp
// When: you try to parse a series of identifier
skip_ws(lex);
// When: you try to parse a string
 std::cout << (void*)(rules::character.target<LexResult (*) (LexerInput&)>() )
        << std::endl;
LexResult result = rules::character(lex);
while (result.is_token()) {
  results.push_back(result);
  skip_ws(lex);
  result = rules::character(lex);
}
```

But `target` is `0` or `nullptr`. Why would this be so even if I'm sure that the two `.cpp` source files' respective `.o` object files are being linked? Why is my global lambda left uninitialized?

Comment: Reduce to a reproducable example, post that.

Comment: Have you heard of [Boost.Spirit](https://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem had to do with [static initialization order](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-intrinsics). Since the lambdas often relied on each other already being initialized in a specific order, the initialization would not happen and the global lambdas would be left in an invalid state, thus causing the `std::bad_function_call` exceptions at runtime.

To fix the problem, I moved the initialization of the global lambda variables to runtime.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that. I should've at least commented to that effect. I avoid global and static variables that have complex initialization that has to occur at runtime for this reason. The iostreams library does backflips to make sure it's initialized before use.